# How does Entity Framework handle transactions?

Tags: c#, transactions, entity-framework-4

Does Entity Framework use a transaction for when you call SaveChanges on your context? Is there any way to turn off transactions completely, or have a certain entity opt out of a transaction?

```
AdventureWorksEntities db = new AdventureWorksEntities();

Product p1 = new Product();
// ...

Product p2 = new Product();
// set invalid data

db.Products.AddObject(p1);
db.Products.AddObject(p2);

// what happens when I call this - does it roll back everything?
// can i tell p2 not to participate in the transaction?
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes**, EF4 will create a new transaction if one does not already exist.  See

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896325.aspx

> When you call SaveChanges, if a
>   current transaction exists, the Entity
>   Framework  uses this transaction for
>   operations against the data source.
>   Otherwise, it creates a new
>   transaction for the operation. You can
>   define transactions by using
>   EntityTransaction, Transaction, or
>   TransactionScope.

**No**, there is no way to exempt a single entity from the transaction.

Not sure about your third question - about whether you can turn off transactions completely, but I'm guessing not based on the above excerpt.

I know this isn't the answer you wanted to hear, but if you want P2 to save regardless of whether P1 succeeds, you would need to save P2 into a *different* object context.

Comment: Try not to add an answer, delete it then add another one. Instead, just edit your original answer.

Comment: Does that original deleted answer still show up when you browse to this question?

Comment: no, but you see it since you are the owner. (You can also undelete it later on.)

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the latest question about turning the transactions off.
Try to create TransactionScope with Suppress [TransactionScopeOption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscopeoption.aspx) to turn off the transactions completely for the code block. Take a look at [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowstransactionsprogramming/thread/25f037ca-886c-4563-b169-d724b6047a99) for some more information.